# Android's NumberPicker displays wrong value when screen orientation changes

Tags: android, numberpicker

I am building a simple custom Dialog for user to enter their current weight using two NumberPickers, which represents weight's integer and fractional parts. These are located side-by-side in a LinearLayout

```
     <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/newweight"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"/>

    <NumberPicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/newweightdecimal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1pt"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have noticed that after screen orientation changes and the activity is recreated, the first NumberPicker always displays the whatever number the second one shows.

Weird part is, that when it's value is accessed programmatically, it returns the correct one. Furthermore selecting + or - on the numberpicker (going up or down the list) gets the NumberPicker to display the correct value again.

For example if before the orientation change first one displays 70 and second one displays 1, afterwards both shows 1. However its getValue returns 70. Also if I select + on the first number picker, it changes its value to 71, as you would expect if it shows 70 in the first place.

Here is the initialization of both NumberPickers in Activity's onCreate method.

```
    NumberPicker newweight = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.newweight);
    newweight.setMinValue(0);
    newweight.setMaxValue(250);
    newweight.setValue((int)Math.round( Math.floor(weight) ));
     newweight.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

    NumberPicker newweightdecimal = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.newweightdecimal);
    newweightdecimal.setMinValue(0); 
    newweightdecimal.setMaxValue(9);
    newweightdecimal.setValue((int)Math.round( 10*(weight - Math.floor(weight))) );
    newweightdecimal.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Does anyone have an idea on why this is happening and how to make sure the NumberPicker displays the correct value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these code in the yours manifest file(in the yours activity class) than data will not change in the both mode of the mobile(landscape or portrait)

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode
```

OR USE SIMPLY THESE

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it simply prevents activity to be recreated on the orientation change. In this specific scenario I use same layout for both portrait and landscape, so I guess it could work for me. However I'd still like to know why this weird thing is happening because it is very frustrating. Of course if no one would have any other ideas I'd mark this answer as correct :)

Comment: Thanks... @rianor ... From my point of view..it prevent activity to recreate therefore data  remain same in the both orientation of mobile (landscape or portrait).

Comment: But in this case the only user interaction is to rotate the phone. Basically I create the dialog, data is shown correctly, then rotate the phone and one of the numberpickers displays an incorrect value. Furthermore what it displays is not its value which I set during the onCreate. Importantly, user does not change the value at any point, android somehow decides to display it incorrectly as a result of the orientation change.

Comment: Actually what...these problem was also occurred with me when i was creating the application for both modes of mobile...than i had searched a lot and just try these above line..and than it worked well for me..therefore i have suggested you to use these code of line in yours manifest file... :)

Comment: Yes I am marking this as accepted, as it did solve my immediate problem and no one was able to offer a better solution. Still, it is only a workaround and if anyone reading this would have an idea on the source of the actual problem, I am still interested.

Comment: ok thanks... @rianor ...Whenever you get the proper solution of these type of problem..than please message me in the same mail chain. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once screen orientation is change activity is recreated so store your number pickers  values in onPause method.
and grab that values in onSaveInstance and set again to number pickers.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that, but I do that already. And it isn't showing values assigned from the onCreate method. Regardless whether the value has been changed from the time when it was created, the left picker always shows the same number as the right picker after the orientation is changed. Most importantly, it is not showing it's own value

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably too late for you, but it may help someone else.

The NumberPicker seems to contain the correct value, but shows the wrong one. (I'm using the Theme.Black NumberPicker style)

I haven't found a way to refresh/repaint/redraw, so I set the value to 0 and then set it again to the value I want in onRestoreInstanceState() (doesn't work for me in onCreate(), it is an extra initialization).

Add the following to onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle):

```
NumberPicker newweight = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.newweight);
newweight.setValue(0);
newweight.setValue((int)Math.round( Math.floor(weight) ));

NumberPicker newweightdecimal = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.newweightdecimal);
newweightdecimal.setValue(0);
newweightdecimal.setValue((int)Math.round( 10*(weight - Math.floor(weight))) );
```

To avoid duplication you could put this in a function and call it from onCreate and onRestoreInstanceState().

I do this to all the NumberPickers and it seems to be an acceptable workaround for me.